# Однократный запуск процесса без ручного запуска приложения юзером

Tags: android

Есть опубликованное в Google Play приложение. В нём реализовано [fcm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) через отправку data-сообщений. В следующей версии я добавил логику по массовой рассылке через [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).

Но проблема в том, что нет гарантий, что все юзеры запустят приложение после обновления и соответственно выполнится подписка на топик.

Как решить проблему? У меня есть несколько идей:

1. Добавить в следующей версии "keep alive" сервис. Он поднимется, я вызыву код, в котором идёт подписка. Но это явно выглядит избыточным. Иметь постоянно висящий процесс приложения ради однократного запуска. Плюс я не уверен, что процесс поднимется после простого обновления в Google Play.
2. Добавить [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). Тоже не айс в свете дополнительного разрешения.
3. Отправить data-сообщение каждому юзеру. Но здесь нет уверенности, что Google одобрит такое поведение. Рассылать надо ~12К юзерам.

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR:** сделать подписку всем юзерам невозможно в принципе (за разумное время и деньги).

3 вариант берите. В массовой рассылке пушей нет ничего страшного, хоть вы и будете это делать нестандартным для массовых рассылок способом.

Вообще идеального способа тут нет - если юзер `Force Stop` приложению сделает то никакие сервисы не запустятся и ресиверы не зарегистрируются в системе. Не факт даже, что пуши придут, но, т.к. они-то гуглом делаются через `GooglePlayServices` то может и дойдут.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Если сделать force close, то да, не прилетает уведомление. Тогда даже не знаю, может и правда keep alive служба поможет или же просто взводить периодически аларм и опрашивать уже свой сервер на "новости".

Comment: @YShinkarev, это тоже не поможет - при `Force close` или очистке данных (которое тоже делает `Force close`) будут удалены все работающие сервисы, все ресиверы будут потёрты из списка зарегистрированных в системе для приёма сообщений и всё такое. Т.е. вы ничего и никак не сможете сделать - вам останется только смириться с тем, что эти юзеры для вас недоступны.